# Adding a continuous running total for a pivot table without stop for year and month

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have seen a article on the net with below address

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot14.html

For continous running total in a pivot table.
 but in this article it removes "year" and "month" field for doing this job. But i would like to work with new feature like time line, so when according to this article i removed "date" field i can not work with "time line" , please help how i can solve this problem

Comment: Sorry, i was using mobile app for putting question, interface are similar, i could not distinguish, i have put this question 2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from your link and the timeline functionality work together just fine. You do not remove the date field

---

**Example**

Below is a detailed example of building the Pivot Table and using the Time Line feature, Using Excel 2016. It should be the same in 2013, and possibly 2010. This example follows the example in your link closely, but adds the timeline at the end.

1) Raw data. Below is a snippet of the raw data used to build the table. It shows 2 years of daily data of orders made by a handful of customers.

[image]

2) Insert a Pivot Table to a new worksheet, using the Raw Data from Step 1.

3) From the Analyze Ribbon, choose PivotTable -> Options. On the Display tab of the PivotTable Options dialog box, check the box for Classic PivotTable Layout.

4) Drag the Date field to the Rows area. Three fields appear - Year, Quarter, Date. Remove the Date and Quarter fields. Select the Year field and choose Field Settings. On the Layout & Print tab of the Field Settings dialog box, choose Show item labels in outline form.

5) Drag the Customer field to the Rows area.

6) Drag the Date field to the Columns area.

7) Drag the Orders field to the Values area. Select the Orders field and choose Value Field Settings. On the Show Values As tab of the Value Field Settings dialog box, choose Show Values as Running Total In, and Choose Base Field: Date.

8) On the Design ribbon, choose Grand Totals -> On for Columns Only. Choose PivotTable Style Light 14. The Pivot table now looks like the following ...

[image]

9) From the Analyze Ribbon, choose Insert Timeline. On the Insert Timelines dialog box, select Date.

10) In the Date Timeline, change the display to show Quarters. Select the third quarter 2015. The PivotTable now looks like the following ...

[image]

11) The numbers are different than the table shown in Step 8, because now it is showing a running total for the 3rd quarter of 2015, instead of a running total for the year.